# stop connection for single client on click in Signalr

Tags: .net, signalr, chat

How do I disconnect a specific client on the click of a button? When the button delete is clicked I want to disconnect the specific client from the chat. I do chatHub.connection.stop(); but it only works on one client, not on every client!

Thanx in advance

Comment: do you want to click a button and disconnect ALL clients connected to the server ?

Comment: No. I want on the click of a button in the browser of a specific user, to disconnect this user from the chat in the specific group that the button identifies(ex. I have a close button in a Chat Room displaying in the browser of a user named MyUser1, and on the click of the close button that holds an id of the group which is also the id of the chatRoom, I want to disconnect MyUser1 from that specific ChatRoom). My problem is when I reconnect MyUser1 to the same chatRoom from which I have disconnected, he reconnects but his name displays 2 times (or 3,4..)

Comment: can you call `Groups.Remove(connectionId,roomName)` ? so your client will call something like `RemoveFromGroup(groupName)` and your server will call `Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, groupName)`. (Assuming you use SignalR groups.)

Answer (score 2):

`chatHub.connection.stop()` is the way to disconnect the client.

If you want to disconnect ALL clients via a message from one client, you have to do it from server.

With current version (SignalR 2.0) here's how you would do it.

1. client sends a message (say `disconnectAllClients`) to the server
2. Server sends a message to all clients to disconnect.
3. Each client calls `chatHub.connection.stop()`

This is because

1. Single client shouldn't be able to disconnect other clients (imagine a rogue client doing this as a DoS or DDoS attack)
2. SignalR v2.0 doesn't have a server-side API to drop a connection at this point. So the client should disconnect.

[Source from asp.net site](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#disconnectclientfromserver)

**Quote:**

> SignalR version 2 does not have a built-in server API for disconnecting clients. There are plans for adding this functionality in the future.  In the current SignalR release, the simplest way to disconnect a client from the server is to implement a disconnect method on the client and call that method from the server. The following code sample shows a disconnect method for a JavaScript client using the generated proxy.

**Security Note from source:**

> Neither this method for disconnecting clients nor the proposed built-in API will address the scenario of hacked clients that are running malicious code, since the clients could reconnect or the hacked code might remove the stopClient method or change what it does. The appropriate place to implement stateful denial-of-service (DOS) protection is not in the framework or the server layer, but rather in front-end infrastructure.